# probability Theory

Tags: probability

I need an explanation on the following problem:

> If you are dealt $3$ cards from a shuffled deck of $52$ cards, find the probability that all $3$ cards are picture cards.

I found the total number of possible combinations, $\binom{52}3=22100$.
now my books uses $\binom{12}3$ to find the number of ways to select $3$ picture cards, which is $220$.

My question is where does the $12$ come from? Why $12$ and not $16$ (number of picture cards on the deck of $52$)?

Thank you

Jorge

Comment: There are 12 "picture cards", kings, queens, and jacks. An Ace isn't a picture I suppose.

Comment: Aces don't count.

Comment: Thank you, it really makes sense now, I was counting the Ace as a picture card.

Comment: Someone voted to close this as off-topic? Sorry, I don't understand the reasoning there.

Answer (score 3):

This is a matter of semantics. What is a "picture card"? I surmise  the book thinks it's the queens, kings, and jacks (giving twelve); but not the aces (but not sixteen).

On the other hand, I would consider many of these [aces](http://www.google.com/search?q=card+ace&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=1KK&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&prmd=imvnsa&source=lnms&tbm=isch&ei=2AGwT57GNoXctgexuqnmCA&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=2&ved=0CBcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1354&bih=1235&sei=2wGwT6i9M4fLtgeHrNzlCA) to be picture cards.  So your interpretation that there are sixteen picture cards might be justified. I suppose it depends on your experience with playing cards. In any case, in my opinion, the problem is slightly vague.

If in doubt of what some particular phrase means in a problem, it would be a good idea to state what your assumptions are in your write up of a solution. Here, if you were adamant in your stance that aces were picture cards, I would say "I take as the picture cards, the queens, kings, jacks, and aces".